# Vue search while typing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have search field and I wish to have the results in real-time,

> I have no issue with returning data or showing data but I need a way to send input value to back-end while user is typing it.

## Code

`HTML`

```
<el-input placeholder="Type something" v-model="search">
  <i slot="prefix" class="el-input__icon el-icon-search"></i>
</el-input>
```

`Script`

```
data() {
    return {
        search: '' // getting data of input field
    }
},
```

[image: one]

I've tried to compute it but it didn't return data

```
computed : {
    searchSubmit: {
        get: function () {
            console.log(this.search);
        }
    }
},
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For side effects as calling backend you can use [Watchers](https://michaelnthiessen.com/difference-between-computed-property-and-watcher/).

```
 watch: {
  search(value) {
    yourApiCall(value)
  }
 }
```